# How can I compute the plotting of a triangle given it's vertices on matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

Given the vertices of the triangle (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3), how can I plot a triangle in matlab with a function? So far this is my attempt

```
function dibujatriangulo(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
x=x2:x1
plot(x, y2+(x2-x1)/(y2-y1)(x-x2)
```

and likewise with the x2 and x3 and, x3 and x1 but it doesn't plot correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A triangle is made of three line segments. I suggest you read the documentation for [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), especially the first form `plot(X,Y)`, where `X` and `Y` are vectors

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @BillBokeey, plotting a triangle is indeed a matter of understanding the `plot` function. In essence, plot(x, y) connect the subsequent points specified by the lists `x` and `y` with line segments. The code below illustrates this in more detail. I hope this helps.

```
% Call plot function
PlotTriangle(0,0,1,0,0,1)


% Function to plot triangle
function [] = PlotTriangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)

    xlist = [x1, x2, x3, x1];
    ylist = [y1, y2, y3, y1];
    plot(xlist, ylist)
    axis([-2, 2, -2, 2])

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use command `patch`

example

```
x=[0 1 .5];y=[0 0 1];
patch(x,y,[1 0 0])
```

the 3rd field colours the patch with red, the 3 components being `red` `green` `blue` desired contents each within range `[0 255]`.

With `patch` you can plot any polygon, not just triangles.